# bokeh + plotting line charts for multi level columns

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have a dataframe with columns as below after a pivot operation;
And now I would like to plot line charts for each of these 8 columns using bokeh.

```
df.columns       
MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['EXT', 'IC', 'INT']],   
labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]],  
names=['SCHED', 'DInd'])
```

I was thinking of utilizing a for loop for this:

```
from bokeh.charts import Line, output_file, show       
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file 
p1 = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", title="All Schedules")    
for col in df:        
        p1.line(df.index, df[col], legend=col)       
output_file("line.html", title="example")       
show(p1)
```

However I cannot seem to call or select the multi level columns properly.
Can you please assist

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should've seen an error like

```
ValueError: expected an element of either String, Dict(Enum('expr', 'field', 'value', 'transform'), Either(String, Instance(Transform), Instance(Expression), List(String))) or List(String), got ('A', 'EXT')
```

which clearly shows that somewhere you pass an incorrect type. In this case, it's `legend` argument of the line glyph function. You can fix the error by e.g. writing `legend=str(col)`.